# What's the correct way to access methods of a member variable in a class pointing to an object?

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-3.5, composition

What's the correct way to define/access methods of a member variable in a class pointing to an object?

For example, I have a class `Foo` that has a method `foo_method`:

```
class Foo:
    def foo_method(self):
        return 'bar'
```

Now, in another class `Bar`, I'd like to store an object to this class (I do not want `Bar` to inherit `Foo`).

What is the correct/recommended way to define class `Bar`?

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

# OR

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

    def bar_method(self):
        return self.foo.bar()
```

The former will allow me to use:

```
x = Bar()
x.foo.foo_method()
```

But, with this I'm directly accessing methods of a member variable (strong coupling).

The benefits I see with this approach are:

- I don't have to wrap every new method that gets added to class `Foo`.
- `Bar` may contain more member variables pointing to other classes. Not 
  wrapping them keeps `Bar` smaller and manageable in size.
- The auto-completion facility from IDE (PyCharm, etc.) or IPython helps 
  inspect `bar` like a menu (`x.foo`) followed by a sub-menu 
  (`x.foo.foo_method()`, `x.bar.foobar()`, etc.) making it easier to develop code.
- Functional programming look-n-feel (not sure if this a pro or con)

The cons are strong coupling, not encapsulating internal details of `foo`, etc.

I wanted to check if this a recommended practice?
And/or if there are any guidelines related to this (kind of implementing a composite pattern)?

Any inputs/pointers will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I found your question a little hard to follow, in that there were many entities labeled "Bar" ( The hand-waved Foo class with a bar method returning "bar" and then the more concrete Bar class definitions, one with yet another bar method ). A little bit of disambiguation would make your question clearer IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I've updated the question and tried to make it more clear.

Comment: That reads much better, thank you.  As to your question, for me it's a matter of opinion and the intended audience.  If you trust your callers to know what to do what the Foo() object, just hand them a Foo().  If there is state that the Bar is maintaining, then you are stuck replicating the Foo interfaces to ensure that it's used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are no real guidelines, but if you make a `bar_method()` that explicitly calls `foo.bar()` and does nothing in between it's the exact same coupling and less convenient.

Python's idioms include "[We are all responsible users](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users)" and in that case, when encapsulation does not provide you any benefit, I personally wouldn't use proxy functions. Leaving it as is results in smaller code which is easier to maintain and is more accessible. Auto-completion as you mentioned is just an added bonus.